# Analyzing bounded, integer/ ranked and weighted data in R

Tags: lme4-nlme

We want to analyze the change of various vegetation indicators where we have plot data on species ID and the associated indicator rank and cover per species.

A short example of the data is pasted in below, with `year` being the predictor variable, `fl_alpha` being the plot ID and `AltiRank4` being one of the vegetation indicators. As a response we so far took an average of `AltiRank` per plot weighted on each species' cover to get a more or less representative value per plot and modeled that with either

```
lmer(weighted_AltiRank ~ year + (1|tr))
```

or

```
glmer(weighted_AltiRank ~ year + (1|tr) , family=gamma(log))
```

depending on the distribution of the weighted indicator (`tr` is some further spatial information). Weighing the indicator with species cover is important for us, since cover might change without the species disappearing etc.

The issues I have with this approach are:

1) The indicator values are bounded between 1 and 6, and linear regression can go beyond that. That is partly cured by using the gamma `glmer`, which cannot be below 0, but still is open to the top. For the weighted average indicators which are close to its lower boundary (i.e. 1) I subtracted the minimal value from all values to make it close to 0, and a gamma fitted quite well. However, for the indicators which are in the middle or close to the top of its range, this doesn't work.

2) The indicator values are whole numbers, and averaging/weighting makes rational numbers out of them. Is this reason enough for a Poisson/ neg.bin. model?

Do you think these concerns matter, and if so, do you have suggestions for alternative analysis approaches?

```
   year  species  cover AltiRank4 fl_alpha
1  1994 PRIMGLUT  1.600         5    1-1-1
2  1994 CARECURV 17.000         4    1-1-1
3  1994 SILEEXSC  1.400         5    1-1-1
4  1994 RANUGLAC  0.150         6    1-1-1
5  1994 POA_LAXA  2.600         6    1-1-1
6  1994 PEDIASPL  0.250         5    1-1-1
7  1994 OREODIST  5.200         5    1-1-1
8  1994 CERAUNIF  0.100         6    1-1-1
9  1994 LUZUSPIC  5.600         5    1-1-1
10 1994 LEUCALPI  2.900         5    1-1-1
11 1994 FESTINTE  0.250         5    1-1-1
12 1994 EUPHMINI  0.400         3    1-1-1
13 1994 MINUSEDO  3.400         4    1-1-1
14 1994 SAXIBRYO  1.100         6    1-1-1
15 2014 POA_LAXA  0.200         6    1-1-1
16 2014 PRIMGLUT  1.300         5    1-1-1
17 2014 RANUGLAC  0.075         6    1-1-1
18 2014 SAXIBRYO  0.500         6    1-1-1
19 2014 SEDUALPE  0.005         4    1-1-1
20 2014 TRISSPIC  0.100         5    1-1-1
21 2014 POA_ALPI  0.400         4    1-1-1
22 2014 LEUCALPI  1.300         5    1-1-1
23 2014 SILEEXSC  1.000         5    1-1-1
24 2014 PHYTHEMI  0.100         4    1-1-1
25 2014 PEDIASPL  0.300         5    1-1-1
26 2014 OREODIST  7.000         5    1-1-1
27 2014 LUZUSPIC  1.000         5    1-1-1
28 2014 FESTINTE  0.250         5    1-1-1
29 2014 EUPHMINI  0.300         3    1-1-1
30 2014 CERAUNIF  0.050         6    1-1-1
31 2014 CARECURV 13.000         4    1-1-1
32 2014 MINUSEDO  2.000         4    1-1-1
```

Comment: From what you say 1 to 6 appears to be an ordered scale. If so, none of the approaches mentioned seems right and I would check out e.g. ordered logit or similar models. Gamma, Poisson, negative binomial all have no defined upper limit and seem a poor match in any case.

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks for formatting and the key word ordered logit models. Now I have something to search for and bumped into the     ordinal package which seems to be for my problem. It's a completely new class of model for me, though, but I suppose I'll find help on that somewhere, too.